# ruby and rails define instance variable in model for belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, instance-variables

I have the following bit of code that works just fine.

```
# app/models/course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lessons, :dependent => :destroy
end

# app/models/lesson.rb
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course

    def previous
        lessons = self.course.lessons.order('date')
        index = lessons.index(self)

        if (index == 0)
            return nil
        else
            lessons.at(index - 1)
        end
    end

    def next
        lessons = self.course.lessons.order('date')
        index = lessons.index(self)

        if (index + 1) == lessons.length
            return nil
        else
            lessons.at(index + 1)
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that the definitions of `lessons` and `index` are redundant. I tried to just pull them 'higher' in scope but no dice:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course

    lessons = self.course.lessons.order('date')
    index = lessons.index(self)

    def previous
        if (index == 0)
            return nil
        else
            lessons.at(index - 1)
        end
    end

    def next
        if (index + 1) == lessons.length
            return nil
        else
            lessons.at(index + 1)
        end
    end
end
```

FWIW, I've been coding quite a bit of JavaScript recently and just returned to Ruby and Rails after a looooong (6 year) hiatus. I think I'm trying to force closure on Ruby but I really dunno what I'm doing wrong.

I've looked for a while and since I couldn't find any useful questions/answers in the canon I thought I'd ask.

Comment: `def lessons; course.lessons.order('date') ; end` ?

Comment: @VictorMoroz, after I added the parallel function `def index; lessons.index(self); end` it worked like a charm. Feel free to answer the question and I'll accept but now I'm wondering about this gray area between a `function` and `variable`. Very interesting, ruby, very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def lessons
    course.lessons.order('date')
  end

  def index
    lessons.index(self)
  end

  ...

end
```